# Coercing lambda function into ignoring non-static member function during unqualified call

Tags: c++

I'm trying inject a `scopePrint()` function call into a `log()` macro such that existing calls to `log()` now print relevant scope information. However, with my current implementation, calls to `log()` within non-capturing lambdas within methods prevent compilation because they default to the member function `scopePrint()` instead of the global. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define log()                                    \
    do {                                         \
        using namespace Game;                    \
        int foo = 1 + 1;                         \
        scopePrint();                            \
        int bar = 1 + 1;                         \
    } while (0)                                  \

namespace Game {
void scopePrint() {
    std::cout << "I'm in the global scope!\n";
}

struct Character {
    void scopePrint() { // if I comment out this function the code compiles
        std::cout << "I'm in Character " << name_ << "'s scope!\n";
    }

    void takeTurn() {
        auto runCalculation = []() {
            int foo = 1 + 1;
            log(); // don't care which one this prints, just want it to compile, but it defaults to an uncaptured Character::scopePrint()
        };
        runCalculation();
        log(); // want this to print "I'm in Character John's scope!"
    }

    std::string name_;
};
} // ns Game

int main(){
    using namespace Game;

    Character character{"John"};
    character.takeTurn();
    log(); // want this to print "I'm in the global scope!"

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to coerce the unqualified `scopePrint()` call from the lambda to target the global instead of the member function?

godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/eo3WjK9Ps

Comment: Why not just capture `this`? `auto runCalculation = [this]() { ... };`

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just call Game::scopePrint() vs ::scopePrint, just to be explicit about which namespace you mean?

Comment: @NathanOliver @Logicrat The existing code has many calls to `log()`, in various places including at global scope, within Character methods, and within lambdas within Character methods. I'm trying to detect whether log() is being called from Character scope or global scope by introducing 2 `scopePrint()`'s that by unqualified calling them, would hopefully tell me the scope. I'm also trying to do this by only changing the Character class, global variables, and macros so that I don't have to change the numerous places where `log()` is called.

Comment: There are ways to figure out within code whether `scopePrint` is a non-static member function, but I don't think there's a way to figure out within code whether a use of `this` (explicit or implied) would be valid, and that's the real issue.

Comment: @aschepler so you're saying there's a way to statically tell if a function member is static or non-static? do you have a hint on how to do that?

Comment: Maybe not. `decltype(scopePrint)` isn't accepted. You could add some sort of metadata to help with that, but there's still no way to get the two statements `log();` in `takeTurn()` to mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

In comments you say

> I'm also trying to do this by only changing the Character class,
> global variables, and macros so that I don't have to change the
> numerous places where log() is called.

Just to be clear @NathanOliver's suggestion, capturing `this` in the lambda, would only alter the Character class, namely the implementation of `takeTurn()` so it meets your stated requirements.

Beyond the above what you seem to be trying to do cannot be done at least because `Game::scopePrint()` and `Character::scopePrint()` do not have the same signatures: `Character::scopePrint()` is a non-static member function. It has an implicit `this` parameter and further it must have one because it uses the `name_` member variable in its implementation and thus cannot be made static.

One option would be to not use `name_` in the character scope print function, make it static, and require all Foo::scopePrint() functions to be static. Otherwise, however your macro works it is going to have to somehow get a `Character` instance to `Character::scopePrint()` to call it. I mean, really you don't need a macro if you are willing to pass a `this` argument to log from member function scopes i.e.

```
 namespace Game {
    void scopePrint();
}

template<typename T>
void log(T this_) {
    this_->scopePrint();
}

void log() {
    Game::scopePrint();
}

namespace Game {
    void scopePrint() {
        std::cout << "I'm in the global scope!\n";
    }

    struct Character {
        void scopePrint() { 
            std::cout << "I'm in Character " << name_ << "'s scope!\n";
        }

        void takeTurn() {
            auto runCalculation = []() {
                int foo = 1 + 1;
                log(); // uses global scope print; to use character, capture this and pass it.
            };
            runCalculation();
            log(this); // "I'm in Character John's scope!"
        }

        std::string name_;
    };
} // ns Game

int main() {
    using namespace Game;

    Character character{ "John" };
    character.takeTurn();
    log(); //"I'm in the global scope!"

    return 0;
}
```